# Cache the contents of the of a 301 redirect?

Tags: caching, squid

We're using squid-cache as a reverse proxy cache. When a request comes in to our squid-cache, in the event of a cache miss, it caches the results from the underlying server. This works great when the server responds with a 200.

Our server, however, sometimes responds with a 301 (permanently moved) with a location header. What I'd like is to cache the contents of the location header (so have squid follow the redirect, see the contents and cache that, rather than the redirect itself).

Is this possible? Does this even make sense?